# How to access website path directly, when hosted from google cloud bucket?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, google-cloud-storage, google-developers-console

I made a website with react, ran the build command, and uploaded the files from `dist` to my google cloud bucket, which shares the same name as my domain.

I have properly routed my cloud console, as well as my domain provider, to direct traffic to the provided `index.html` in the bucket, and everything from there works. As in, you can access `www.XXXX.com` and it loads and runs properly.

I have also created an ssl certificate following the documentation, and now my site is secured with https.

My problem here is that I cannot navigate to a specific path within the site eg: `www.XXXX.com/auth`

Am I missing a step in the bucket configuration? or is a static website not able to accept path on the root domain?

All of my code for the website logic is in a file `/assets/index.44250449.js` , except for the index.html which runs the mentioned file as a script.

I uploaded all of my source files to google cloud bucket.
Used `gsutil web set -m index.html gs://www.XXXX.com`

I expected the all of the paths to work because in development, `localhost:5173/auth` would always load the auth page. Same goes for all other routes.

Comment: i'm experiencing exactly same problem... have you found any solution for it..?!! OTL